# Parameters for Yelp API v3.0 Search for IOS

Tags: yelp

I am using Yelp API v3.0 in my ios app development.
And I can't find how to set price filter to my search result.
For example, I wanna get the result with "$$$" , "$$".
At that time, I need to add a parameter about the price in the request to search.
According to the documentation, they tell me that the parameter name is "price" and to meet my demand, I can set price parameter as  "2,3".
But it doesn't work.
I hope yelp developers can help me!
Thank you.